# Is there a way to get a list of Hadoop cluster machines from one of the data nodes?

Tags: cluster, hadoop, discovery

I have access to a data node in a Hadoop cluster, and I'd like to find out the identity of the name nodes for the same cluster. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the configuration file of the datanode, specifically `hdfs-site.xml`. It will list the namenode that the datanode will try to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

use below script

```
#!/bin/bash
date >> list_of_datanodes
bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report > dfsstat.txt
cat dfsstat.txt |grep 'Datanodes available' --color >> list_of_datanodes
cat dfsstat.txt |grep 'Name:' --color >> list_of_datanodes
rm -rf dfsstat.txt
```

Comment: Recursively deleting the `dfsstat.txt` files seems like overkill.